# Initial Delay When Using Mouse Keys

Tags: c++, windows, system32

I am trying to create a script to simulate mouse movement in a video game I play to counter recoil. I used to use **AHK** but with the recent update they are now looking for `dllcall().`

To get around that I am trying to implement the Mouse Keys feature in Windows Accessibility. There is one problem though, when using mousekeys there is an initial delay upon using it and it also has acceleration rather than a constant speed.

I want to remove both the delay and acceleration but I do not know where to look and what to change. I found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373593(v=vs.85).aspx but im still struggling to find out what file or library the code for Mouse Keys is in.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Post your code. Keep it small please.